# kartosa/postgis docker impossible to connect except for pgadmin

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin-4

This is a problem that has been nagging at me for days. I have read several posts and tried so many solutions but to no avail (So I sincerely beg for help from those who have solved the same problem):

[image]

```
services:

  postgis:
    image: kartoza/postgis:${POSTGIS_VERSION_TAG}
    container_name: postgis
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASS=${POSTGRES_PASS}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
      - ALLOW_IP_RANGE=${POSTGRES_ALLOW_IP_RANGE}
      - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=${POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS}
      - POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME:${POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME}
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - postgis-data:${POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME}
    networks:
      - postgis_network

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:${PGADIM_VERION_TAG}
    container_name: ${PGADIM_CONTAINER_NAME}
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD}
      - PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE:${PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE}
    networks:
      - postgis_network
    volumes:
      - pgadmin-data:${PGADIM_DATA_VOLUME}
        #depends_on:
      #postgis:
      #condition: service_healthy

  cloudbeaver:
    image: dbeaver/cloudbeaver:23.1.0
    container_name: cloudbeaver_container
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8085:8978"
    volumes:
      - cloudbeaver-data:/opt/cloudbeaver/workspace
    networks:
      - postgis_network



volumes:
  postgis-data:
  pgadmin-data:
  cloudbeaver-data:

networks:
  postgis_network:
      driver: bridge
```

my `.env` file

```
POSTGIS_VERSION_TAG=15-3.3
POSTGRES_USER=admin
POSTGRES_PASS=password
POSTGRES_DB=elevation
POSTGRES_ALLOW_IP_RANGE=0.0.0.0/0
POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_EXTENSIONS=postgis,hstore,postgis_topology,postgis_raster,pgrouting
POSTGRES_DATA_VOLUME=/var/lib/postgresql


PGADIM_VERION_TAG=6.14
PGADIM_CONTAINER_NAME=pgadmin4_container
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=admin
PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE=False
PGADMIN_PORT=5050
PGADIM_DATA_VOLUME=/var/lib/pgadmin
```

[image]

At this point, I can connect to the database with pgadim but not with other systems such as cloudbeaver:

[image]

and

[image]

So with pgadmin4 I can connect to the postgresql databse. The problem (which I can't explain) is that pgadmin4 is the only tool with which I have access to the database contained in the container. If I try the same procedure with cloudbeaver, for example, I get the following error message:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Compare the hostname which is configred in both programs.  If you want them to do the same thing, you should configure them in the same way.

Comment: In one case you connect to a server `postgis`, in the other case to `localhost`. That is probably a significant difference.